# Modify jquery plugin livefilter to search title tag

Tags: jquery

I am trying to modify the plugin [livefilter for jquery](http://pastebin.com/zYcTFVVc). I need it to search the title tag of an an LI as well as its contents.  I have already modified it slightly (@ line #32) so that it does not hide matches, instead it will bold them as well as change the background to all matches.

I tried modifying the following lines:

```
     /** Case insensitive :contains jQuery pseudo selector */
  $.expr[":"].icontains = function(obj, index, meta, stack) {
    return (obj.textContent || obj.innerText || jQuery(obj).text() || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(meta[3].toLowerCase()) >= 0;
  };
```

adding this to the returned statement:

```
|| jQuery(obj).attr('title')
```

But this does not seem to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware than because of OR operator `||`, the test stops as soon one of the part is true, the other "parts" will not be tested at all (hopefully I'm clear).

This kind of writing is typically used because of the differences between browser's implementations, that might or not have such properties.

This is the case in the following context: `textContent` is not supported under IE<9, so `obj.textContent` will be evaluated as false, then `innerText` will be evaluated and so on. The last `|| ""` ensures a string is finally returned so the code does not break.

Another use of this kind of syntax is to ensures an object is defined, like this:

```
function foo(bar) {
    var _bar = bar || {};
    // if "bar" is undefined, "|| {}" will be returned
    // we can now surely work with "_bar"
}
```

Further reading:

- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent)
- [innerHTML, innerText, textContent, html() and text()](http://www.davidtong.me/innerhtml-innertext-textcontent-html-and-text/)

---

What you want is the content **and** the title attribute, so try this:

```
(obj.textContent || obj.innerText || jQuery(obj).text() || "") + jQuery(obj).attr('title')
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/xT6Cc/)**

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.. I didn't realize it wasn't reaching the statement... got it working now...

Comment: I have re-phrased a little my answer because it was kinda messy. Glad it helped though.

Comment: Thanks again, I ended up switching it from title to .data('keywords') because some of the keywords didn't make sense being placed in a title tag. I am really starting to like html5's data- attribute.

Comment: It is a better solution I think also. These are really changing the way we correlate data with markup. I was getting a bit tired of using bizarre class names also.

Answer (score 2):

If you're inserting jQuery(obj).attr('title') inside the "()" that will be "lowerCased" it will not work.

The OR operator stop the sentence when any of the tests returns TRUE, so you will need to put your code as the first test instead the last, but it will be a mistake, since the :contains pseudo-selector is only for the element content.

Other way to do what you want is to modify your selector to something like this:

```
$("someSelector :contains(text), someSelector [title*=text]")
```

Remember, alter the jQuery code is dangerous, but modify a plugin code isn't